# Change the Display name of the Bot in the notification of a call

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

My company registered a Bot with the name CompanyCallBot and we'd like to change the name when the Bot starts calling.

I have an endpoint which creates an online meeting and start inviting participants and Microsoft Teams displays a box with the following information: "CompanyCallBot wants you to join a meeting".

What I'd like to do is to replace the name of the Bot by the Organizer. For example: "Ayane wants you to join to a meeting". The reason is because having the Bot name, the participants don't know who is calling.

A solution could be to set the Subject of the meeting to:
Subject = "on behalf of {Organizer's name}"
, this way you receives a call with the next display information: "CompanyCallBot wants you to join on behalf of Ayane".

Such approach doesn't work very well in mobiles because you can either receive calls with the following notifications:
"Unknow"
"Group call"
"Group call on behalf of Ayane"

How can I substitute the name of the Bot during the call by the organizer and how to control what it is displayed in mobiles.

Comment: The closest one i see is that you need to grab the bot's id and try to see if you can update the displayname property of it. You also need to see in above scenario whether it works or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but such solution will update the Display name in Azure and I'm not able to request the permissions: Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy, Application.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All. Each time a call is raised it is going to update the Display Name in Azure :(  Is there a possibility to include this feature in next releases of inline editing the DisplayName of the Bot only for ongoing calls and not in Azure?

Comment: I hear you, but i dont think such option exist at this point; if you find, please do share it. Being said that you can [consider filing an uservoice/feature request with Teams](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359626), so that they can consider implementing it.